# "no such sysroot directory" while building qt project

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

MacOS **Mojave** Version 10.14 (18A389).

Today I updated Xcode to version 10.0 (10A255). End when I try to build my Qt project I get an error:

```
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from ../greed/timediagram.cpp:1:
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/QtGui:3:
In file included from /Users/arsenyspiridonov/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Headers/QtGuiDepends:3:
In file included from /Users/arsenyspiridonov/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QtCore:4:
In file included from ../../../Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qglobal.h:47:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/utility:202:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/cstring:61:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/string.h:61:15: fatal error: 'string.h' file not found
#include_next <string.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [timediagram.o] Error 1
16:13:47: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта greed (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.9.1 clang 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
```

What's the problem? How to fix it?

Answer (score 11):

add 'QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.14' to your .pro file, and manually delete .qmake.stash from your build directory (or directories).

Comment: *.pro file — Qt project file? Where I have to write it?

Comment: There are no .qmake.stash in directories under MacOS

Comment: .pro file is created by QtCreator ... .qmake.stash is created in the target build folder of the application.

Comment: Simply deleting the .qmake.stash from my debug and release build directories solved the problem with no .pro editing, after upgrading from Sierra->Mojave, for me.

Comment: Simply deleting the .qmake.stash from my build directories solved the problem with no .pro editing.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I updated xcode to the last version, so instead of have on the folder the version 10.13, I had MacOSX10.14.sdk ( that is a symbolic link to the folder MacOSX.sdk)

so, you can solve the problem with this code on terminal:

```
sudo ln -s MacOSX.sdk/ MacOSX10.13.sdk
```

positioned on the current folder.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I just reinstalled Qt. All is Ok now

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

1. Close the project in Qt Creator.
2. Delete the `.pro.user` file in your **code** directory.
3. Add `QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.14` and `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.14` to your .pro file in a text editor (not in Qt Creator). Replace `10.14` with whatever MacOS version you want to build for.
4. Re-open the project in Qt Creator. It will reconfigure.
5. Build.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to sellen's Answer: If you have trouble locating your `.qmake.stash` file, or if you don't have a `.qmake.stash` file in your build folder, try locating it using the terminal:

```sh
find /path/to/base/folder -name ".qmake.stash"
```

In my case I had a `.qmake.stash` file in my build **parent** folder, but not in my build folder. Not sure how it got there but somehow QMake picked it up and as soon as I deleted it and restarted Qt Creator things started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

the fast solution is to create new shotcut in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs folder, you can copy the exist shortcut, them change the name you need.

Answer (score -2):

This happen to me recently and my Xcode needed to update. So I would recommend quitting xcode and trying to update your current version to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: The question states that Xcode had been updated, so recommending updating it is not useful.